# Getting error while try to login in django admin database

Tags: python, django

after running the server when I try to login Django admin page I'm getting this error "unable to open database file".

here is the important part from my settings.py:

```
    """
Django settings for DX4C_Django project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-64ls#+8!6xkg$mm08a1qpa$^(3njksma@^o=u_%yc$&5gsqtux'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello',
    'import_export',
    # 'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'django_ssl_auth.SSLClientAuthMiddleware',
    ]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DX4C_Django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DX4C_Django.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3"),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = [MEDIA_DIR,]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

How to solve this problem?
here's the error screen
[image]

This one is the working code previously but suddenly getting this error. not able to log in into admin database because of this error

Comment: Should be`BASE_DIR + "/db.sqlite3"`. The way you do it right now is you are dividing `BASE_DIR`with `"db.sqlite3"` which doesn't make sense

Comment: Show us the full error output!

Comment: @bdbd Not if `BASE_DIR` is a `pathlib.Path` or one of its subtypes.

Comment: Oh really? Ok thanks TIL

Comment: @KlausD. updated the question with error

Comment: Did you run migrate?

Comment: Yes. Actually that's a working code. suddenly getting error

Comment: I just tried your setting file and it's working for me. Could you please share the coding repo for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

By default, we have this snippet for sqlite3 database configuration. so please let paste this snippet to your settings.py and enjoy.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
}
}
```

Comment: not working. Giving this error "TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath
"

Comment: In that case, kindly delete the sql file and migrate all the migrations. Make sure place above snippet which I mentioned.